# Passing an optional function to a component best practice

Tags: angular

I am creating a component in angular that accepts user input. As the user enters new items and submits them, the items are added to the list, it's a bit more complex than that but let's keep it that simple.

I want the developer to be able to define a `beforeAdd` function if they desire. The developer can implement a function that matches the function signature, and tell the component to use that function for `beforeAdd`, The return value of that function (if no null ) would be added to the list.

**Question:**

What is the proper way to tell the component about said functions, how should I pass that function to the component as best practice?

I just did this in my component and it works great, but passing a function in as an Input feels too simple and hacky, and fear I am opening myself up to problems I am unaware of.

```js
@Input() beforeAdd?: (s: string) => string | null;
```

```js
if (this.beforeAdd && typeof this.beforeAdd === 'function') {
   s = this.beforeAdd(s);
  // s = this.beforeAdd.call(this,s); // Possibly
}
```

I would **greatly appreciate any** feedback. *If this is acceptable, Angular has once again blown my mind.*

Comment: I think this is fine, passing a function down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is acceptable. It's not like it's an Angular thing. It is the functional programming that is supported by javascript. It was supported better by javascript than OOP for a long time. While nowadays it's changed.

It doesn't seem like a good practice. It looks like the logic is spread between components. The more clear solution I see is the is concentrate the logic of addition in the parent component. The child component would only have an output property to signal about the item addition

```js
@Output() onAdd: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

Parent HTML:

```
<my-child (onAdd)='addTheItemIfSomething()'></my-child>
```

Parent typescript:

```js
addTheItemIfSomething(item: string) {
   if (this.canAddItem(item)) {
      doAddItem();
   }
}
```

This would also let to follow the well-proven dump-smart (presentation-logic) component architecture approach.

Also passing a function as an input IMO is a road to callback hell. I would try hard to avoid it. While I'm not 100% sure I would come up with the approach to avoid it in all the cases (: